# Is there a way to get a list of my pages in Elementor's Userdefined code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, elementor

I've been translating a website, and I've chosen not to use a plugin to do this. I'm also not interested in adding a plugin for it. What I want is to be able to use my selfbuilt language switcher to change the current site to the version in the language selected (such as changing the Danish FAQ page to the English FAQ page when you click the british flag). This language switcher is placed in my site's header.
I could simply read the location.pathname using JavaScript and then run an if statement with all my pages typed in statically like so

```
var switcherDanishUrl = SOMEOBJECTDESIGNATION;
var myPath = String(location.pathname).toLowerCase();
if (myPath === "en/frontpage" || myPath === "en/frontpage/")
{
   switcherDanishUrl.href = "mypage.dk/forside"
}
```

But this would make adding future pages a pain, and it's not very pretty either. Rather, I'd like to be able to get the pages programmatically, and then do something like slice off the location, leaving just the path, and then splitting that into the language path and the page path, and put them into something like a 2 dimensional array getting a structure like [dk,frontpage] and [en,frontpage]. Then I'd be able to compare the current URL to every element in this array and set my link when my if statement (in this case value1 === "dk" or value1 === "en") matches the first statement, and the page path matches the second value.

I've not been able to find anything about this type of problem elsewhere.

Comment: If all your page URLs are named the same, only the presence or absence of the leading `/en/` making the difference - then I am not sure why you would need a list of all pages to begin with. And if that is not the case - then a mere list of all pages probably won't do you any good either, you'd need a way to tell what is the translation of what, to begin with. Can't tell from your description, if you implemented anything to make that connection.

Comment: Originally I planned to give them the same name and the leading /en/ was the only difference, but it's more SEO friendly if I name them according to their language. So it'd be mypage.dk/forside and mypage.dk/frontpage, I'll go correct that in my question

Comment: Okay, and how have you made the "connection" between the two? Any list of pages would only help you, if it would let you determine _that_ those two are translations of each other.

Comment: A valid point, I completely forgot that translating the URL would invalidate my method. If I could get my pages including its relations, specifically with the hreflang property and the link, that'd probably work. I wouldn't even have to compile a full list of my pages then, I can just get every variation of a given page from one.